Aws Workspace Client cannot be opened in Ubuntu - 20.04.6 LTS
I've been using these versions of Aws Workspace client(3.1.0.813 / 4.7.0.4312) for Ubuntu(20.04.2 LTS / 20.04.6 LTS) without any issues in the last time, connecting to Aws Workspaces thar are using PCoIP protocol.
The company newest Aws workspaces are using only the WSP protocol which comes up with some improvements, instead of PCoIP.
In order to be able to connect to the new company's workspaces, I needed to upgrade the client. I've followed this official page: https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/linux-install . I've downloaded and install the latest client(2024.0.470) which supports both protocols PCoIP/WSP.
But the issue that I was facing is that I cannot open the client after the instalation.
These are the errors from the Ubuntu syslog:

Apr 17 13:47:05 com.amazon.workspacesclient.desktop[9069]: thread 'main' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: Error { kind: Uncategorized, message: "creation time is not available for the filesystem" }', /codebuild/output/src781068905/src/git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/SoloClient/src/linux/client/src/infrastructure/logging/log_utils.rs:111:18


Apr 17 13:47:05 com.amazon.workspacesclient.desktop[9069]: note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace


Apr 17 13:47:05 systemd[2219]: gnome-launched-com.amazon.workspacesclient.desktop-9069.scope: Succeeded.

Also, I've tried to look for a previous version, in order to give it a try, but it seems that AWS ONLY points to previous versions for Windows and MacOS: https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/Versions
Also another interesting thing, is that if I'll upgrade Ubuntu to 22.04.X, there are clients available only for WSP. Please check: https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/linux-install
Could you please tell, which version of the client to use, or give it a go, in order to support both protocols, for Ubuntu(20.04.6 LTS).

It seems that, if you follow the exact steps from the Aws page: https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/linux-install , you will end up having a default desktop entry that will point to: /usr/share/applications/workspacesclient.desktop . The problem with this desktop entry, is that it does not contain any Exec command..
After I've identified the correct desktop entry which is: /usr/share/applications/com.amazon.workspacesclient.desktop, I've encountered the error posted in the question.. The Exec for this entry was: Exec=workspacesclient %u.
I've did some tests, and I've identified, that if I try to open this desktop entry with sudo like this: sudo gtk-launch com.amazon.workspacesclient.desktop it will work !!!
So, in order to have a desktop entry in favorites, I've modified the Exec command like this: Exec=sudo -i sh -c workspacesclient %u and everything looks good now :)
I'm not sure why the workspacesclient process needs the sudo, but otherwise it will display the error posted in the question..
Good luck with it ! Later one I'll upgrade my system to 22.04 Ubuntu, and I'm curious to see if things will work. The advantage of using 20.04 for now, is that you have an Aws Workspace client that supports both protocols: PCoIP and  WSP
